# Can't access MetaMask accounts via Dapp UI

Tags: metamask

I'm trying to initiate a transaction onClick of a button on my UI, however on load web3.eth.accounts is returning emtpy, is this because Im running locally? does MetaMask not work locally?

Yet when I run 'web3.eth.accounts' in the console, it returns addresses relevant to MetaMask

Comment: Put more information....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say "running locally", you make me think you're initializing a separate web3 object that is not initialized with MetaMask's provider object.

To use MetaMask accounts, you should be initializing any local web3 instance from the injected metamask provider, as shown in this example:

https://github.com/MetaMask/faq/blob/master/DEVELOPERS.md#partly_sunny-web3---ethereum-browser-environment-check

Comment: Thanks, yes this was the problem I was initializing a web3 object with both MetaMask and infura, this was conflicting with 'to: address' attribute and returning a invalid address error

Answer (score 0):

You can configure Metamask to work with your local test node. On the top left corner where you see the fox icon wyou can click where it says Ethereium Main Network and select localhost:8545 or add a custom RPC address.